# C# Compare Months

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to check if the selected month is already past.

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(DDMonths.SelectedItem.Text).Month > DateTime.Now.Month)
{
      //logic here if date is not in the past
}
```

`DDMonths.SelectedItem.Text` value is `April`

However I am getting the following Format exception error:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ToDateTime` cannot understand your date format, you need to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) instead:

```
if(DateTime.ParseExact(DDMonths.SelectedItem.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month > DateTime.Now.Month) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can parse the month by name with the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DDMonths.SelectedItem.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month
```

However, you'd be better off making the `Value` of each element in `DDMonths` the integer value corresponding to the month instead, if possible.

Comment: Definitely a way to go. Save yourself time from parsing dates and introduce data/presentation separation. Use the `Value` of the dropdown to track the number of the month, and `Text` to display the name in whichever language user chooses. Then you simply do `if(DDMonths.SelectedItem.Value > DateTime.Now.Month)`.

Answer (score 1):

it means that your line

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(DDMonths.SelectedItem.Text)
```

is giving you error. You should use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DDMonths.SelectedItem.Text,"MMMM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

So the `Text` of your `DropDownList-Item` is not convertible to `DateTime` with the current culture. So maybe you are showing the month-name (what i assume) or the error is more subtiel. You could use the `ListItem.Value` to store the datetime in a specific format, for example:

`"yyyyMMdd"` -> `"20130726"`

Then you can parse it in this way:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20130726", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to allow the monthname:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact("July", "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just looking for the number of the month, why parse it to a `DateTime` at all?  You can just get it from the `DateTimeFormatInfo` directly:

```
string input = "April";

var months = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;
var monthNumber = 1 + Array.FindIndex(months, x => x.Equals(input, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
if (monthNumber > DateTime.Now.Month)
{
    // ...
}
```

Do think about what you want to do if it is currently April.  Depending on what you are doing, you may want to compare using `>=`.

Also, if you are writing a desktop application, this code (and the others) are just fine.  But if you are writing a web application and this code is running server-side, then you have two additional concerns:

- The culture should match the input.  You may need to use a different culture, or the `InvariantCulture`.
- You are comparing to `DateTime.Now` - which will be in the *server's* time zone.  So if a user in another part of the world uses this on the 1st of their new month while your server is still on the prior day, then your comparison will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `ParseExact` variant of `DateTime`

```
DateTime.ParseExact("April", "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month // outputs 4
```

you should also try using the `Value` (*DDMonths.SelectedItem.Value*) component and fill it as needed